# Angular 2 RC with express server instead of lite server

Tags: node.js, express, routes, angular, server

I would like to create single page application with latest angular 2 rc and express server.I don't know how to link both with out bower,gulp and webpack.
There are some starter pack available but can't get the expected one.Please guide me

Comment: thnks @echonax will check it out

Comment: hi @echonax I've checked your link and got one doubt how the server identify index.html and how to make additional routing

Comment: thnks once again @echonax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is really broad but here's a github starter projects link with express and rc.1: [Angular 2 starter project with express](http://www.github.com/echonax/Ng2-rc1)

The server identifies index.html from `app.use( express.static(__dirname + '/client' ) );` line. This means look for a file that is named *index.html* under client directory.

You can add aditional routes for backend to *routes.js*. For client side, like navigating through the pages and stuff I suggest you to take a look at angular2's routing tutorial/documentation: http://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html