# Angular 2, Spring boot , spring security , login form

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a **Front end** application that runs on `http:// localhost:4200`, with *angular 2* (I've used `angular-cli` for generating the project).
The application runs without any problems (I can get and post info from/to database using *Angular 2* `Http` service:

```
getList () {
    return this._http.get("http:// localhost:8080/").map(res => res.json());
}
```

On the other hand, I have a **Back end** application running with *spring boot* on `http:// localhost:8080/` (note the ports), that provide a REST Api for my *angular 2* application.

Sending requests from `http://localhost:4200/` to `http://localhost:8080/` works as expected.

Before I've programmed an application with *spring* framework & *angularJS 1*, *spring* security took care of login and security in the same app (maven project).

Now I have two separate applications that are communicating via `http` (RESTful Api with spring boot , and front end Api with angular 2)

How can I set my login form and where to put it, and how to configure *spring* security with my *angular 2* application?

Comment: Have you had any researches yourself? Try add your results instead of pure asking.

Comment: i've tried to send the form from angular to rest service and stock it, but when  the page reloaded , i should repeat the credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you spin up the Angular Application with Angular CLI, your Angular Pages are served by NodeJs in the backend. 
You have a couple of options here.

1. The login can be handled at NodeJS server which can in turn invoke
   Spring Boot application to Authenticate and Authorize.(I think, you might need to do some tweaks like using express server instead of lite server. take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561973/6785908)
2. After initial development, you can copy over your AngularJS
   resources to a Spring MVC (Spring Boot) server and use it to serve
   your pages (as well as the rest APIs), just as you were doing
   before.
3. Make the Angular App invoke the spring boot Service (I guess , you
   are using the $http.post to submit the form, if that's the case you
   can just change the URL so that it can hit spring boot app instead.)
   For the production deployment, use nginx/httpd to serve the static
   files (AngularJS/CSS etc) and route/proxy all the dynamic request to
   the spring boot app.

I would strongly suggest the 3rd option.

Comment: Hi there, I am also struggling with this issue, although I'm quite new to spring. In your 3rd option when you suggest altering the url to hit the spring boot app could you please clarify how this is different to the OP's code sample? His url appears to point to the spring boot app. My app (really an angular app + a spring app) runs as expected with out spring security but when I post user credentials to spring security's default /login url I am getting a 'Request method 'POST' not supported' and my understanding was that you had to post it. Thanks